# Are there any instances in our scriptures where sagotra marriage was done?

Tags: scripture, marriage, gotra

Q:-Are there any instances where sagotra marriage was carried out?

Q:-How the outspring of sagotri marriage were looked upon?

Q:- Is there any prasyachit for doing sagotra marriage?

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow hehe what made u ask such question?

Comment: Sorry for hurting you.

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow not at all got hurt.But what made u ask this question?

Comment: My ignorance made me do that